# When 24hrs are up, delete nodes from firebase database

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I start with some seed data that uploads data to Firebase when I run my server. After 24hrs, some new data has been added by users but the moment 24hrs go by, I want to delete all the user data except for the original seed data that I uploaded.

What is the best way to have some sort of timer that check when 24hrs go by? I'm guessing the first step is to have a timestamp field in my seed data to track when the data is uploaded and then I need to figure out how to create the timer that calculates the difference

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want to do, it sounds like you may be looking for `cron jobs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase doesn't support `cron jobs` or `scheduled tasks`. You need to use a third party system to trigger a clean up function.

The function itself would be fairly easy to write, you could just do a query on any value older than 24 hours then delete it.

The Firebase team did a great video on how to setup `cron jobs` which would work in your scenario.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA